# Can’t connect to mysql docker image

Tags: mysql, jenkins, docker, liquibase, docker-container

I have issue using mysql/mysql-server docker image.
I want to connect to mysql server, create db, user with all PRIVILEGES to have ability to create new schema and run liquibase in future.

I run container like this:

```
sudo docker run --name db -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=qwe123 -e MYSQL_DATABASE=test \
  -d -p 3306:3306 mysql/mysql-server:5.6 --lower-case-table-names=1
```

when I do `docker ps` I see that it's running but when I'm trying to run liquibase (using root/qwe123) it failed with:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sql-maven-plugin:1.5:execute (default-cli) on project db: null,  message from server: "Host '172.17.0.1' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server" -> [Help 1]

tried with user:

```
sudo docker run --name db -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=qwe123 -e MYSQL_DATABASE=test \
  -e MYSQL_USER=admin -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=qwe123 -d -p 3306:3306 \
  mysql/mysql-server:5.6 --lower_case_table_names=1
```

with admin user have error creating new schema, it looks like admin has only access to test database:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sql-maven-plugin:1.5:execute (default-cli) on project db: Access denied for user 'admin'@'%' to database 'test2' -> [Help 1]

with root the following error:

> [ERROR] The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server. Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.

Also tried to set privileges for admin in init command:

```
docker run --name db -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=qwe123 -e MYSQL_DATABASE=test -d \
  -p 3306:3306 mysql/mysql-server:5.6 --lower_case_table_names=1 \
 '--init-connect=CREATE USER `admin`@`localhost` IDENTIFIED BY "qwe123"; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO `admin`@`localhost` WITH GRANT OPTION; CREATE USER `admin`@`%` IDENTIFIED BY "qwe123";GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO `admin`@`%` WITH GRANT OPTION;FLUSH PRIVILEGES;'
```

In this case for root user have error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sql-maven-plugin:1.5:execute (default-cli) on project db: null,  message from server: "Host '172.17.0.1' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server" -> [Help 1]

for admin -  the following:

> 12:13:57 [ERROR] The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server. Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.

Also tried to use localhost and 127.0.0.1 as host to DB, always have error with connection.
Any ideas?

Comment: Unless you are using an external storage volume that isn't mentioned here for data, each `docker run` may be creating a new data store. You may want to try running your `CREATE USER` attempt using `docker exec` instead of `docker run`. That would use the already-running container instead of creating another new container.

Comment: The difficulty is that I want to run docker image in Jenkins job.
And in Jenkins I can't open -ti mode for docker exec.

Comment: So I can add user like this:  
   `sudo docker run --name db -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=qwe123 -e MYSQL_DATABASE=test -d -p 3306:3306 mysql/mysql-server:5.6 --lower-case-table-names=1
  docker exec -ti db mysql -uroot -pqwe123
  CREATE USER `admin`@`localhost` IDENTIFIED BY "qwe123";
  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO `admin`@`localhost` WITH GRANT OPTION;
  CREATE USER `admin`@`%` IDENTIFIED BY "qwe123";
  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO `admin`@`%` WITH GRANT OPTION;
  FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Comment: And then I can connect with admin user and create db. 
  `docker exec -ti db mysql -uadmin -pqwe123`
  `CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS test2`
  
  But in Jenkins I can't do: `docker exec -ti db mysql -uroot -pqwe123`
  As have error: the input device is not a TTY
  So the best decision would be to create user and DB running docker image.

Comment: I don't see why you would need `-ti` to run the exec here, have  you tried without `-ti`? You only need `-ti` to have an interactive session.

Comment: Without -ti I have error about socket: `Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
 ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)`

Answer (score 3):

You should allow the user within MySQL to connect from the IP of your host machine.
Do not forget to flush privileges after changing user in MySQL

`GRANT CREATE USER ON *.* TO 'root'@'%';`

And restart the mysql instance

Also there is a chance to have mysql bind to 127.0.0.1 via my.cnf. If it is so - change the bind to 0.0.0.0 to get it accessible via any IP

Comment: Tried to add ` FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` after user creation, but didn't help.

Comment: ```GRANT CREATE USER ON *.* TO 'root'@'%';```
And restart the mysql instance

Comment: Also there is a chance to have mysql bind to 127.0.0.1 via my.cnf. If it is so - change the bind to 0.0.0.0 to get it accessible via any IP

Comment: Great, I could connect to DB using root user if I do:
`docker run -p 3306:3306 -v /tmp:/tmp --name db --detach -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="qwe123" -e MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=% -e MYSQL_DATABASE=social -d mysql/mysql-server:5.6 --lower_case_table_names=1 --init-connect='GRANT CREATE USER ON *.* TO 'root'@'%';FLUSH PRIVILEGES;'`

Comment: But how to create another user? I tried to do:
`docker run -p 3306:3306 -v /tmp:/tmp --name db --detach -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="qwe123" -e MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=% -e MYSQL_DATABASE=social -d mysql/mysql-server:5.6 --lower_case_table_names=1 --init-connect='GRANT CREATE USER ON *.* TO 'root'@'%';CREATE USER `admin`@`%` IDENTIFIED BY "qwe123";GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO `admin`@`%` WITH GRANT OPTION;FLUSH PRIVILEGES;'`

Comment: But in this case when I connect admin user I have error:
`[ERROR] The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server. Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.`

Comment: I would try to build docker image with Dockerfile and init needed users before starting container itself.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the following Steps to play with the docker container with yours external client ie dbeaver , mysql workbench etc

### 1- Run the following docker mysql command

open your terminal i.e bash | zsh | cmd

Note :: mysql/mysql-server is my image of mysql ...
yours may be different otherwise it will pull new image if not present

```
docker run -d -p 3306:3306 --name mysql-test -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=1234 mysql/mysql-server
```

### 2-open mysql CLI

open your terminal run below one after another to run cli

> mysql-test is container name;

```
docker exec -it $(docker ps -q -f name='mysql-test') bash -l;
```

---

```
mysql -uroot -1234;
```

> cli will look like this " mysql > .... " in terminal

### 3- Create New user and grant privileges

Note :: change username and password with your own user in below commands run on your terminal

```
SE mysql;
CREATE USER 'new_usernmame'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'new_usernmame'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

### RESULT

Congrats you can now make jdbc connection with newly created user

### FOR MORE DYNAMIC SOLUTION

SEE
https://mohsin-ejaz.gitbook.io/docker-notes/docker-mysql/dockerize-02